# Pandas Groupby Return Average BUT! exclude NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So Im trying to make sense of the pandas groupby function and to reduce a large data frame I have. Here is an example:

```
                             A        B
2016-09-23 19:36:08+00:00   NaN     34.0
2016-09-23 19:36:11+00:00   NaN     33.0
2016-09-23 19:36:12+00:00   24.1    NaN
2016-09-23 19:36:14+00:00   NaN     34.0
2016-09-23 19:36:17+00:00   NaN     34.0
2016-09-23 19:36:20+00:00   NaN     34.0
2016-09-23 19:36:22+00:00   24.2    NaN
2016-09-23 19:36:23+00:00   NaN     34.0
2016-09-23 19:36:26+00:00   NaN     34.0
2016-09-23 19:36:29+00:00   NaN     34.0
2016-09-23 19:36:32+00:00   24.1    NaN
2016-09-23 19:36:33+00:00   NaN     34.0
2016-09-23 19:37:00+00:00   NaN     34.0
2016-09-23 19:37:02+00:00   24.1    NaN
```

So I have 2 data series "A" and "B" that were sampled at different rates with their sampling time as the index of the original data frame.

I would like to now group the rows of the data frame by date/hour/minute and return the average of the data per minute. Here the average should ignore the missing values in the data frame.

So for example, I would return something like this:

```
                             A        B
2016-09-23 19:36:00+00:00   24      34.0
2016-09-23 19:37:00+00:00   24.1    33.0
```

Is it possible to do this with a built in pandas function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.mean.html), which compute mean of groups, excluding missing values:

```
print (df.resample('1Min').mean())
                             A          B
2016-09-23 19:36:00  24.133333  33.888889
2016-09-23 19:37:00  24.100000  34.000000
```

Another solution with `groupby`:

```
print (df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('1Min')]).mean())
                             A          B
2016-09-23 19:36:00  24.133333  33.888889
2016-09-23 19:37:00  24.100000  34.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. These are both nice looking solutions. But for me they come back with an error : "
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate". Could this be because the index of my data frame has datetime objects?

Comment: No, it means your columns are not converted to numeric. Try `df.A = df.B.astype(float)` and `df.B = df.b.astype(float)`. If it return error, there is another possible solution, so question is how does work `astype` casting ?