# pandas data aggregation and alignment

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, aggregate

I have two data frames with timeseries data.  One is (generally) hourly data, the other contains points that are (typically) every 30 seconds, but not necessarily cleanly aligned on hour boundaries.

I want to realign my 30-second data such that values are averaged for the hour-long period in the hourly data.

For example, if my hourly data is:

```
1:01AM     50
2:02AM     60
```

All my 30 second values between 1:01AM and 2:02AM would be averaged and given a timestamp of 2:02AM, so I could more easily compare it to the hourly data.

I could of course do this manually, but I suspect pandas offers a clean solution, but I can't find the right command.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838367/pandas-groupby-return-average-but-exclude-nan) is of any help.

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values

Comment: There are many existing questions on [\[pandas\] groupby custom time](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+groupby+custom+time) and related terms.

Comment: Following Evgeny Pogrebnyak's link: merged = pd.merge_ordered(df1, df2, on='ts', how='outer'); resampled = merged.resample('1H').mean() works, but only because one of my datasets is clean and happens to follow nice hour boundaries.  I want to make the resampling work regardless of what data frequency I have.